# Does QNetworkReply always emit finished()?

Tags: qt, qnetworkreply

I read the document of signal finished() , it does not say the finished() is always emitted. And I read the error() signal:

> void QNetworkReply::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code) This
>   signal is emitted when the reply detects an error in processing. The
>   finished() signal will probably follow, indicating that the connection
>   is over.
>
> The code parameter contains the code of the error that was detected.
>   Call errorString() to obtain a textual representation of the error
>   condition.
>
> Note: Do not delete the object in the slot connected to this signal.
>   Use deleteLater().
>
> See also error() and errorString().

Does the line `The finished() signal will probably follow` mean that, under some conditions, the QNetworkReply does not emit finished() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For QNetworkReply error signal we can certainly expect error codes that don't mean broken connection. For instance:

> QNetworkReply::ContentNotFoundError   203 the remote content was not
>   found at the server (similar to HTTP error 404)

The connection is definitely not finished yet in the case above. No finish signal emitted.

> QNetworkReply::RemoteHostClosedError  2   the remote server closed the
>   connection prematurely, before the entire reply was received and
>   processed

The connection is definitely finished then. And finish signal was emitted.

Comment: Could you give some example that connection is finished at error() ?

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError, RemoteHostClosedError and few more.

Comment: I have read the source code of QNetworkReply, all error signals are followed by a finished signal as far as I can find. Could you give some demo to show the case the error signal is emitted and finished signal is not emitted?

Comment: The demo would involve the server. I use finished signal like      connect(&m_networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(handleFinished(QNetworkReply*))); to analyze an exact cause of failure.

Comment: So if the reply do not emit signal finished() according to your answer , how could you analyze its cause of failure?

Comment: No signal - no *fatal* failure. We have the app with many users.

Comment: My question is about whether the finished signal will be always emitted by QNetworkAccessManager after I sent the request. Your first answer have some mistakes, now it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83506/discussion-between-alexandervx-and-zzy).